# COM Component opens dialog - how to handle in ASP Classic

Tags: com, asp-classic, event-handling

I'm trying to copy an approach (for authenticating users of our ERP system) that a colleague developed in a VBA environment, and implementing it in an existing ASP Classic application.

The ERP supplier has supplied a COM Provider for their application. We supply the users' ERP credentials and we use the component to confirm that they are valid.

I *thought* I was following my colleagues approach, and when I supply valid credentials it does work, but when I supply invalid credentials, it locks the application.

Digging deeper, it appears that if the credentials are valid the method call returns a value and execution continues as expected. But if the credentials are wrong, a dialog box appears. My colleague trapped this event in his VBA app, automatically cancelling the dialog, which returns control to the original calling function.

VBA Code sample:

```
Private WithEvents m_oServer As Server

Private Sub m_oServer_RequestCredentials(Identification As String, Password As String, Cancel As Boolean)
   'Dialog will appear unless we cancel it
   Cancel = True

End Sub

Public Function Check_Logon_Credentials() As Boolean
'starts here   
   If m_oServer.Invoke("ClientApplication", "IdentifyCurrentUser", m_oResult, sibtRecord) Then
      Check_Logon_Credentials = True
   Else
      Check_Logon_Credentials = False
   End If

   'Do more stuff

End Function
```

It appears that m_oServer_RequestCredentials is an event handler exposed by the component, that the VBA is able to intercept, cancelling the dialog.

The question is how can I copy this in my ASP application - is there a similar way of creating an event handler (that can cancel the dialog)?

Or am I going to have to wrap the call to this component in another component, which *can* intercept the dialog box?

Any other solutions?

Comment: perhaps you could run that vba/windows script from classic asp with WScript.Shell object and then catch the return code with the exec method of WScript.Shell? (not tested it)

Comment: The problem is that this code is running on the server, so there can be no user interaction. I need to handle the event somehow, so I can prevent the attempt to open the dialog.

Comment: yes and therefore you could try to run that vbs on the server (which prevents the dialog from opening as i understood it) with the wscript.shell object.

Comment: I've actually found a way of using the component 'silently', so my problem is solved. However, this question is about handling events in ASP Classic so I'll leave it open for now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle events with pure server-side asp classic code. You need to handle these type of events with client-side VBScript but unfortunately client-side VBScript only works with internet explorer. here is the sample code of [client-side VBScript](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/):

```
<script language="VBScript">
    function mybutton_OnClick()
        answer = MsgBox("2+2=4?",vbYesNo,"Math Test")
        if answer=vbYes then
            MsgBox "Congratulations!",vbOkOnly+vbInformation,"True!" 
        else
            MsgBox "Go learn Math!",vbOkOnly+vbCritical,"Wrong!" 
        end if
    end function
</script>
<input type="button" value="Math Test" name="mybutton">
```

You can copy the code above and paste it in notepad, and save as ".html" file then open it in IE.